# Improving/fixing and condensing a variable 0-1A 0-20V 25W linear power supply circuit design

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, linear-regulator

So, in a previous [a previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/639490/using-a-series-regulator-to-produce-a-control-signal-for-a-voltage-controlled-po/639625#639625) I was trying to come up with a way to set up a voltage control block for a dubiously specified voltage controlled power supply. I've since come to a working solution for the control voltage block, but I've found new issues with the circuit, so I'm presenting a new question with more specific questions and more in-depth explanation of the desired outcomes.

So, the power supply I'm trying to design is trying to fulfill the following criteria:

- It has to transform 19.5 VAC into its own DC, I'm simply doing a full wave rectification here.
- The voltage output of the supply shall be adjustable between 0-20V
- The current limit of the circuit shall be adjustable between 0-1A
- The control voltage for both current and voltage has to be at, or under 4V (each, not total) with two potentiometers, TL/LM431 and 2 potentiometers (and other passive bubblegum components)
- The supply has two working states: current-limited state where the load is trying to draw current that is more than the current set via the current control voltage, in which case the maximum current that has been set dominates the output at load. The other state is the normal state where the current is at, or below the set current limit, and the load shall see the voltage set via voltage control voltage over it.
- The voltage and current regulation should be combined around the same power transistor, which it is not in the current design

Summary:

Power-supply 0-1A, 0-20V, power-limit is dominated by 19,5 Vrms which should translate to about 25V@1A. Output adjusted via two control voltages between 0-4V. In my configuration I've set the voltage to have a control voltage of 0-4V and the current to have 0-1V. Picture of my current design:

[image: Current circuit design]

The problems I'm currently facing:

- Something in the circuit is drawing way too much power. Whether it's the fundamental design or if I have some incomprehensible component sizes or -choices, I'm unsure, but I can tell that the power limit was not met while the voltage control block was utilizing ideal DC instead of the general power line, so the operation until adding the control voltage block was under the power limit, but adding control voltage block of my design put it over the limit.
- I have two power-transistor setups instead of one, so I would like to try and combine the two Darlington setups I have. I'm uncertain as to how, for now, but that is something I'll definitely have to figure out. Doing this might improve the power performance of the circuit slightly, but I'd be surprised if it was enough alone
- Not a problem per se, but the rest of the circuit can be under as much scrutiny as deemed necessary, as I would not be surprised if it had some other illogical design choices, but they're secondary to the aforementioned goals in my list of priorities. All general improvements I'll try to incorporate, though

I had another design I was trying to work on at an earlier stage that I scrapped because I couldn't work out how to have the current limiting actually limit current (lower op amp in the picture), in case anyone wants any legwork if the entire design above seems too nonsensical. This one doesn't have the actual AC power I'll be working with nor the actual control section, because I stopped working on this at a rather early stage, but they would be identical to the above design

[image: Earlier, alternative design]

Comment: I've not read your earlier post. But I can read specs, above. If you really need to get all the way down to exactly 0 V, it really helps simplify things if you have a negative supply rail. And how precisely do you need to be able to set a current that is very near to 0 A? (And any time I see an opamp as a follower, output to (-) input, without a capacitor somewhere I start wondering how well the design has been crafted.)

Comment: The load should be almost at 0V and 0A at the 0A configuration, but it's unnecessary to reach absolute zero. It's hard for me to say the exact range I want to reach, but I believe it should be fine as long as the load current / Voltage are in the ballpark of <1mA <10mV in case it simplifies things as well